# Should "Augmented" in RAG (Retrieval Augmented Generation) be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

RAG is a popular approach used in Generative Artificial Intelligence (Generative AI).

Of the major technology organisations, Microsoft Azure's site shows "Retrieval Augmented Generation" without a hyphen, for example,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/retrieval-augmented-generation-overview.

AWS uses a hyphen - https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/retrieval-augmented-generation/.

Which one is correct?  I feel comfortable using a hyphen since "retrieval-augmented" describes the generation (a generated piece of text or other formats).  But I also feel that "generation" is used to describe the process of (text or other) generation, not the generated output.  Does that change things?  Thanks.

Comment: By definition, generation means the creation of output, not the output. So that doesn't matter. But there is often a trend away from hyphens, so one good example without is enough for me. We used to have on-line, on-site, health-care.